# Building an Array From a Column of Values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a project in which I'm taking a list of aircraft and standardizing their names (i.e. C-206T, C206, C-206 are all a C-206, etc).  Column B in my Worksheet has all the various aircraft types that need to be standardized.  There are 3353 rows of data.  I'm attempting to put all the unique names in that column into an array and then dumping that array into a column onto I'm using on a different Worksheet so I can assign the standardized names to them.

I'm using the following code:

```vb
    
Sub UniqueAircraft()
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim ArrayCount As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NumEntries As Long
    
    Worksheets("Imported Times").Select
    Columns("B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    
    If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Selection
            If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
                tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
    
    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
    
    arr = Split(tmp, "|")
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If (arr(i) <> "") Then
            ArrayCount = ArrayCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
            
    Worksheets("Aircraft").Select
    Range("B1:B" & ArrayCount) = Application.Transpose(arr())

End Sub
```

Some of the entries from the original list are not making it into the second Worksheet.  For example, C-206T and C206 are there, but C-206 isn't. Another example - C-172RG makes the list, but C-172 doesn't.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the was InStr compares the strings, but I just can't figure it out and a couple hours of internet searching has not helped.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: The "normal" approach here is to use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to get the unique items.

Comment: A data set that causes the problem, **posted as text**, along with your desired output, would be useful in helping you. Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It may be that a fuzzy match would work better for your purposes.

Comment: The way you are testing if an entry is already in the list does partial matches.    Eg `C-172` matches `C-172RG`.

Comment: If you have Excel 365 you can do this without vba using the `UNIQUE` function

Answer (score -1):

Apparently it is related to character Length limitations on your temp variable.
Try to put the result directly into the array insted using | and spliting afterwards.